# How to convert a Hydro launch file to an indigo launch file

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you in advance for your help, I have the following launch file which runs well on other ubuntu 12.04 systems with ros hydro.
My system is ubuntu 14.04 with ros indigo, and the files do not work. I believe the problem is within the launch file shown below, along with the error I receive.

```
<launch>
  <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true"/>
  <node pkg="stage_ros" type="stageros" name="IGVC_stage" args="$(find stageroscam)/world/20Mx20M.world" output="screen">
  </node>
 <!--include file="$(find stageroscam)/rviz.launch"/-->
 </launch>
```

Error:

```
raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)
ResourceNotFound: stageroscam
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/martin/catkin_ws/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/indigo/share
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195920/how-to-convert-a-hydro-launch-file-to-an-indigo-launch-file/) by [udmamrl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4590/udmamrl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2014-10-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is not in your launch file.

A `ResourceNotFound` error means a resource was not found!

In this case, it is the package you are trying to find in `$(find stageroscam)`. That hints the package is not installed/available on your system.

You should either install the package (if it is available), or clone the git repo in your catkin workspace. Mind you the package may not yet be compatible with ROS Indigo.

---

Originally posted by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) with karma: 806 on 2014-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [udmamrl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4590/udmamrl/) on 2014-10-27**:
Thanks, I had the Stageroscam files in the wrong folder.